# Создание плагинов log4j

Tags: java, jar, log4j

Пытаюсь написать свой Layout. Пишу простейший класс

```
package test;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.MessageLayout;

@Plugin(
    name = "TestLayout",
    category = "Core",
    elementType = "layout",
    printObject = true
)
public class TestLayout extends MessageLayout {
    @PluginFactory
    public static Layout<?> createLayout() {
        return new TestLayout();
    }
}
```

в файле конфигурации его вообще не упоминаю

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" strict="true" packages="test">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT"/>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

(наличие или отсутствие атрибута `packages="test"` на картину не влияет)

В проекте еще один класс

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Test {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("test");
        log.error("Test");
    }
}
```

при запуске из Intelij все работает (а если еще добавить свой Layout в конфигурацию, то он тоже начинает работать). А вот при запуске jar получаю картину

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n
```

Что я делаю не так? Если убрать класс TestLayout из проекта, то jar тоже начинает работать

**Update**

Если установить

```
log4j2.debug = true
```

и сравнить логи при наличии плагина и при его отсутствии, то получается такая картина:

- при наличии

  ```
  DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
  DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0,104801 seconds to load 205 plugins from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f
  DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 44 plugins
  .........
  DEBUG StatusLogger Installed 1 script engine
  DEBUG StatusLogger Oracle Nashorn version: 1.8.0_25, language: ECMAScript, threading: Not Thread Safe, compile: true, names: [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript], factory class: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
  DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 116 plugins
  DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
  DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
  ```
- при отсутствии

  ```
  DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
  DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0,001875 seconds to load 1 plugins from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f
  DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 0 plugins
  ...............
  DEBUG StatusLogger Installed 1 script engine
  DEBUG StatusLogger Oracle Nashorn version: 1.8.0_25, language: ECMAScript, threading: Not Thread Safe, compile: true, names: [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript], factory class: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
  DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 1 plugins
  DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
  ```

т.е. получается, что мой плагин почему-то мешает загружаться всем остальным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина найдена.

Список плагинов подгружается загрузчиком из бинарного файла

```
<JAR>/META-INF/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/Log4j2Plugins.dat
```

Я собираю один jar со всеми зависимостями.

Когда я не определяю своего плагина, туда попадает `Log4j2Plugins.dat` из log4j-core-2.11.0.jar`. Когда же я определяю свой плагин, то в этот файл заносится информация только о моем плагине, перетирая стандартный список.

Варианты решения проблемы описаны здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065580/log4j2-custom-plugins-annotation-processing-with-maven-assembly-plugin

- либо разводить свои плагины и стандартные по разным jar
- либо использовать maven плагин `log4j2CacheTransformer` для слияния этих двух файлов

  ```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
      <configuration>
          <transformers>
              <transformer
                  implementation="com.github.edwgiz.mavenShadePlugin.log4j2CacheTransformer.PluginsCacheFileTransformer" />
          </transformers>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>com.github.edwgiz</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin.log4j2-cachefile-transformer</artifactId>
              <version>2.8.1</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```